# Unusual looking for and while loops used in a quicksort (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, loops, quicksort

Please take a look at this snippet code from and implementation of quicksort, it's from the book [Data Structures and Problem Solving Using Java](http://catalogue.pearsoned.co.uk/catalog/academic/product/0,1144,0321546229,00.html) :

```
    int i, j;

    for(i = low, j = high -1;;){

        while(array[++i].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
            ;
        while(pivot.compareTo(array[--j]) < 0)
            ;
        if(i >= j)
            break;
        swapReferences(array, i, j);
    }
```

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how this works. From my understanding the for loop just declares the starting point and doesn't contain any rules on when to finish the for loop; that's handled by the if statement, is that correct?
Also, without the brackets I'm not clear about the while loops. the semi-colon and lack of indentation suggested they're not nested. But there's no actual code within the loops. 
Am I correct in saying each while is separate, one compares lower values to the pivot and one compares higher values, swapping when each of the while loops criteria are met. As the i is incremented and j is decremented every time the for loop carries on with the process until the criteria for the if statement are met at which point it breaks from the for loop? 
Is this correct?

EDIT: Updated code to reflect exactly what was in the book.

Comment: You are right but you can step through the code in your debugger if you want to check what each line does.

Comment: Just this statement is wrong: But there's no actual code within the loops. The `;` is actually a proper operation (an empty one)

Comment: It would be better style to put the increment and decrement operations into the bodies of the while loops.

Comment: whoever wrote that code is in the business of obfuscating code.   everything about it screams unmaintainable.  and why in the world would you use a-b<0 instead of a<b?

Comment: @thang  Out of cluelessness I suppose. Due to overflow it is not even transitive.

Comment: That "a-b < 0" was my fault. in the book the author used ".compareTo" to compare contents of the arrays. I couldn't get it working like this with int arrays. Without thinking, I changed the code from ".compareTo" to "-". Very silly. I was in a panic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. The `while` loops do their work implicitly, with `++i` and `--j`. It could be rewritten for more clarity as

```
do i++; while (array[i] < pivot);
do j--; while (pivot < array[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loops are empty - the actual work is done in the increment and decrement operators within their predicates.

The for loop is also effectively an infinite loop, which is only exited by the break statement when i >= j.

Its slightly odd syntax - and Im not sure Id write it this way - might be premature optimisation...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct in your assessments.

Omitting boundary conditions and step directives is not that uncommon. You even see

```
for (;;) {
...
}
```

quite often, to construct an unbounded loop. On a side-note, stricter code-conventions (NASA, mission-critical, real-time systems) expressively forbid unbounded loops in the code.

The `while` construct is legal, but very ugly. I would not accept that construct if I was reviewing code from someone on my team. For one, I am very strict in requiring curly brackets around all conditional and loop blocks, even if they are only one line.

Consider this syntactically legal construct and contemplate what it does

```
int i = 0;
while (i++ < 10)                                                                ;
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the for loop is just used for initialization.There is no increment or any rule specified in for loop.It means  the for loop will continue until a it hits abreak statement.

while(array[++i] - pivot < 0);
This means the each step i will be incremented by one and check the condition.This while loop will contine until (array[++i] - pivot ) equal to or greater than 0.
Then execution will go to next while loop
while(pivot - array[--j] < 0)
This while loop will contine until (pivot - array[--j] ) equal to or greater than 0.
Then it will check the if condition.If it is satisfied, it will break from main for loop.
Otherwise the function swapReferences gets executed and for loop will continue.